# Calculating paths through a tree for a match algorithm

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to develop a function to search through a treeish structure and return complete paths to all nodes which pass a simple string test (indexOf).
I think I'm somewhat close as I can handle N root nodes of arbitrary depth, as long as the paths are linear. The problem occurs when I branch off as what should happen is that each branch becomes a distinct array containing its entire path. However, what is happening is that each branch is being merged into a common array representing the matching paths underneath all children of that parent where the branch occured.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tbH0FW6T11F3iwNIBHdN?p=preview

Simple search showing correct results with no branching in the data
[image]

Search showing incorrect/merged results with branching in the data
[image]

In the above image the result should contain three elements each representing the distinct paths traversed (String test matches on 'Z').
[1aa,1a,1],[1aba,1aa,1a,1],[2aa,2a,2]

Comment out the "Zoe" entry in the data to switch between linear and branch tests.

```js
(function(){
  
  var data = 
  [
    {"name" : "Mike" , "id" : "1","children" : 
    [
      {"name" : "Jim" , "id" : "1a", "children" : 
      [
        {"name" : "Zoe" , "id" : "1aa", "children":[]}, //Uncomment for fail test
        {"name" : "Carrie" , "id" : "1ab", "children" :
        [
          {"name" : "Zane" , "id" : "1aba", "children":[]}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]},
    {"name" : "Allen" , "id" : "2","children" : 
    [
      {"name" : "Fred" , "id" : "2a", "children" : 
      [
        {"name" : "Zach" , "id" : "2aa", "children" :
        [
          {"name" : "Dean" , "id" : "2aaa", "children":[]}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]}
  ];
  
  var rFX = function(val,item){
    
    var subMatches =[];

    subMatches = (item.children.map(function(child){
      return rFX(val,child);
    }));
    
    subMatches = [].concat.apply([], subMatches);
    
    if(item.name.indexOf(val) > -1 || subMatches.length >0){
      subMatches.push(item.id);
    }
    
    return subMatches;
    
  };
  
  var result = data.map(function(item){
    return rFX("Z",item);
  });
  
  console.log(result);
 
})();
```

Comment: Re-think how the return value of `rFX` should look like. Then check whether what you're doing with the results of the recursive calls is correct.

Comment: Rethinking now, trying a different approach as I don't see how this one can avoid merging subtrees.

Comment: How do you define "subtree"? Is it an array of path-arrays?

Comment: @Bergi, yes... Each array in the final result is supposed to represent a complete path to a sinlge matched node. Currently the algorithm is merging subpaths/subtrees into a single array instead of keeping them distinct. The correct result of the alogrithm for the data in the snippet would be [1aa,1a,1],[1aba,1aa,1a,1],[2aa,2a,2]

Comment: Yes, you will need to merge the multiple arrays of paths into one array of paths (where each path is still an array). But then you still have an array of paths. So what are you going to do with your current `item.id` now? (And what does the posted code do?)

Comment: "And what does the posted code do?" , ref the images as they show the output and I have the code attached in a snippet you can run either here or you can follow the link to the plnkr. Basically the line "subMatches = [].concat.apply([], subMatches);" is flattening more than it should.

Comment: No, that line is actually OK. I was referrring to `.push(item.id);` - it is not nested enough, given that `rFX` *should* return an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned my initial approach as the complication of merging the data as the recursive calls returned up the stack seemed too difficult.

Instead I broke the problem down into two functions.

1. getAllPaths : this function traverses the entire structure computing an array of all possible paths to a leaf node. No filtering is performed here. Each recursive invocation is passed an array of the nodes processed previously in its path. When the function reaches a node with no more children it adds the final path to the array and then places the path array on a master array which all recursive invocations have closed over.
2. filterPaths : this function nibbles each path (bottom up) in the collection returned from getAllPaths until it finds a match thus leaving us with a collection of paths to our matched items.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tbH0FW6T11F3iwNIBHdN

```js
(function() {

  var data = [{
    "name": "Mike",
    "id": "1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Jim",
      "id": "1a",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Zoe",
          "id": "1aa",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Carrie",
          "id": "1ab",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Zane",
            "id": "1aba",
            "children": []
          }]
        }
      ]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Allen",
    "id": "2",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Fred",
      "id": "2a",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Zach",
        "id": "2aa",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Dean",
          "id": "2aaa",
          "children": []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }];

  //Return all complete paths in the data (paths to leaf nodes)
  var getAllPaths = function(items) {

    //Array which all calls will push their completed path arrays onto.
    var master = [];

    //Recursive call to travese every path in our data.
    var rFXi = function(item, itemArray) {

      itemArray.push(item); //always push current item

      //If we still have children process them recursively
      if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
        item.children.forEach(function(child) {
          rFXi(child, itemArray.slice());
        });
      }

      //else we are at a leaf node so push complete path array onto master.
      else {
        master.push(itemArray);
      }

    };

    //boot up our recursive calls
    items.forEach(function(child) {
      rFXi(child, []);
    });

    return master;
  };

  //Test our paths against a comparator function and,
  //remove all path segments beneath a terminal match
  //and then return only those paths remaining with a
  //length greater than zero.
  var filterPaths = function(paths, comparator) {

    paths.forEach(function(path) {

      var matched = false,
        length = path.length,
        i;

      for (i = path.length - 1; i >= 0 && !matched; i--) {
        if (comparator(path[i], "D")) {
          matched = true;
        } else {
          //remove non matching leaf
          path.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }

    }); //forEach end

    return paths.filter(function(path) {
      return path.length > 0;
    });

  };

  //Retrieve all paths to leaf nodes in our "tree"
  var paths = getAllPaths(data);
  console.log(paths);

  //Now filter those paths for matching segments
  paths = filterPaths(paths, function(item, val) {
    return item.name.indexOf(val) > -1;
  });
  console.log(paths);


})();
```